# Adding Facebook like button hides other site content

Tags: blogengine.net

I am using the latest version of [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/), and I want the share buttons of Facebook, linked in, [Google Buzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Buzz), etc. to go below the menu, but after adding the Facebook, LinkedIn, and Buzz button code, the content next to it disappears. It seems BlogEngine.NET prevents entering script tags or something so this would be a limiting issue. How can this be fixed?

The code is below, see the BUTTON CODE section.

```
<code>
    <div class="login">
        <span runat="server" id="aUser"></span><a runat="server" id="aLogin" />
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li><a1 href="<%=Utils.AbsoluteWebRoot %>" rel="home"><%=Resources.labels.home %></a></li>
        <li><a1 href="<%=Utils.AbsoluteWebRoot %>archive.aspx"><%=Resources.labels.archive %></a></li>
        <li><a1 href="<%=Utils.AbsoluteWebRoot %>contact.aspx"><%=Resources.labels.contact %></a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=Utils.FeedUrl %>" class="feed"><img src="<%=Utils.ApplicationRelativeWebRoot %>pics/rssButton.png" alt="Feed" /><%=Resources.labels.subscribe %></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(BlogEngine.filterByAPML())" class="apmlfilter"><%=Resources.labels.filterByApml %></a></li>
        <% if (Utils.IsMobile)
           { %>
        <li><blog:MobileThemeSwitch ID="MobileThemeSwitch1" runat="server" /></li>
        <%
           }
        %>
    </ul>
</div>
</code>

<!--BUTTON CODE -START-->
<code>
    <div id="Div1">
        <script src='linkedinurl' type='text/javascript' /> <script data-counter='right' data-url='mysiteurl' type='in/share' />
    </div>
</code>
<!--BUTTON CODE -END-->
<code>
    <div id="content">
        <blog:SearchOnSearch runat="server" MaxResults="3" Headline="You searched for" Text="Here are some results for the search term on this website" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server" />

        <p id="footer">
            Powered by <a href="url">BlogEngine.NET</a> <%=BlogSettings.Instance.Version() %><br />
            Theme by <a href="url">Mads Kristensen</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode it:

Like this:

site.master

```
<div style="float:right; padding-left:10px" class="TwitterButton">
    <div>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url=
            <%=Server.UrlEncode(Post.AbsoluteLink.ToString()) %> data-text="
            <%=Server.UrlEncode(Post.Title) %>"> Tweet</a>
        <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output would look like this:

```
<div style="float:right; padding-left:10px" class="TwitterButton">
    <div>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
            data-url="http://www.kbdavis07.bloggersonline.com/post/Using-HitSniffercom-
            with-BlogEngineNet.aspx" data-text="Using HitSniffer.com with BlogEngine.Net"
            data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>
        <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code above is for Twitter, and I don't have a working example of LinkedIn code.
But it should be about the same.